# Keep selection on QTreeView when updating the model

Tags: qt, qtreeview

When I select some rows in the QTreeView, and trigger an event that reloads the model, the selection is lost.

```
tree = QTreeView()
tree.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

// Every time an event is triggered, update the model
model = QStandardItemModel(rowCount, columnCount)
tree.setModel( model )
```

I know that the rows may have changed, but it's does not matter, all I want is to select the same rows ( by index ).

Answer (score 0):

1. Before resetting model, you need to get list selected indexes from selectionModel.
2. After reloading model, you need to set back this list.

It will work, only if your model is idential. But it is danger to keep raw `QModelIndex` after it became invalid. In your case, if your model is plain (without), you may keep not `QModelIndex` but `QPair< int, int >( row, column )`. In any case, you need to create your own mechanism to identify, what items needs to be selected.